# Вопрос с Android manifest unity

Tags: android, unity3d

В проекте есть FaceBook SDK с папкой Plugin-Android- и здесь файл AndroidManifest

с содержанием:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
package="com.unity3d.player" 
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:installLocation="preferExternal" 
          android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <!--<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="20"/>-->
  <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <!-- Local Notifications -->
    <receiver android:name="com.androidnative.features.notifications.LocalNotificationReceiver"> </receiver>
    <!--<receiver android:name="jp.ne.donuts.localnotifications.NotificationReceiver"></receiver>-->
    <!-- Block End -->
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityAppLinkActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityGameRequestActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityCreateGameGroupActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityJoinGameGroupActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.AppInviteDialogActivity" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="fb&" />
    <provider android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider&" android:exported="true" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Мне необходимо добавить плагин GoogleMobileAds (Admob) который в свою очередь тоже пытается создать такую же папку Android, тоже создает AndroidManifest, но с другим содержанием:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This Google Mobile Ads plugin library manifest will get merged with your
application's manifest, adding the necessary activity and permissions
required for displaying ads.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.unity.ads"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:versionCode="1">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
      android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <application>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Как с этим справляться ? Ранее для теста интегрировал все по отдельности, как уложить все вместе и что бы работало не имею опыта, надеюсь на вашу помощь)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1. Unity принимает основной манифест Android.
2. Unity находит все Android-манифесты ваших плагинов (AARs и Android-библиотеки).
3. Манифесты из плагинов объединяются в основной манифест с использованием класса манифеста Google.
4. Unity изменяет манифест, автоматически добавляя разрешения, параметры конфигурации, используемые функции и другую информацию в манифест.
```

Вот тебе 2ой пункт поможет, создаешь подпапку и туда еще один манифест добавляешь

[Документация](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-manifest.html)